# Asp-route-id: passed integer becomes 0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following problem.
I have a product for which I run some tests.
In my cshtml page, I show the test runs for some product item, like this:

```
<td><a asp-action="TestDetail" asp-route-id="@Model.ResultViewModels[i].TestRunId">Content</a></td>
```

TestRunId is an integer. For example, TestRunId could be 9. This works: the URL looks correct.
In my cshtml page, the user can click on this, to see more details.

However, when I log the asp-route-id in my controller, this TestRunId seems to be 'lost'. In my example below, the second logging shows `testrunId: 0`. I expect this to be also 9.

```
        public IActionResult TestPlanRunDetail(int TestRunId)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("TestPlanRunDetail function called.");
            logger.LogInformation("TestRunId: " + TestRunId);
            // Omitted for brevity
            return View(detail);
        }
```

Comment: Change to _asp-route-testrunId_ or change the parameter name to _id_ See docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1#asp-route-value

Answer (score 2):

The parameter name in `asp-route-xxx` must be same as the parameter name in the backend `(int xxx)`

So, change one of your param names to match the other

Answer (score 0):

### [`asp-route-{value}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asp-route-value) is an [Anchor Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

> The Anchor Tag Helper enhances the standard HTML anchor (`<a ... ></a>`) tag by adding new attributes. By convention, the attribute names are prefixed with `asp-`. The rendered anchor element's `href` attribute value is determined by the values of the `asp-` attributes.

#### The Reason:

> Any value occupying the `{value}` placeholder is interpreted as a potential route parameter

Therefore, if you use `asp-controller="controller" asp-action="action" asp-route-id="@Model.ResultViewModels[i].TestRunId"`.

The generated HTML `href` will be `href="/controller/action?id=0">Content</a>`
where `0` is the actual `@Model.ResultViewModels[i].TestRunId`.

Notice that the parameter name in `href` is `id` instead of `TestRunId`?

Your `TestPlanRunDetail(int TestRunId)` take `TestRunId`, but not `id`, and that is why you get `TestRunId=0`.

#### The Easier Solution:

Change `asp-route-id` to `asp-route-TestRunId` (or `asp-route-testrunid` as it is not case sensitive).

#### Alternate Solution:

Define a default route template in `Startup.Configure`:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

In the model:

```
<a asp-action="TestDetail" 
   asp-route-id="@Model.ResultViewModels[i].TestRunId">
       Content
</a>
```

Then, the generated `href` will be `href="/TestDetail/12"`.